# java, extending class with constructor in superclass

Tags: java, constructor, extends

I have a class that defines field "coordinates" which is an array without length and a subclass where i need to set a length of array to work with it.So the question is how do I change the array of coordinates' length in subclass. Here is the code: 
Superclass:

```
abstract class Vector implements sample {       

    private int[] coordinates;  

    public Vector (int[] coordinates) {

    }
}
```

And subclass :

```
class Vector3D extends Vector {

    public Vector3D(int[] coordinates) {
        super(coordinates);

    }
}
```

Comment: One problem here is the `private` class member `coordinates`, which will **not be inherited**. Maybe it works with `protected int[] coordinates;`, but I am not sure...

Comment: First of all, you probably want that the constructor of the superclass assigns the passed parameter to the corresponding class member. For the rest, I really don't know what you're asking.

Comment: _how do I change the array of coordinates' length_ - Not at all. An array has a fixed size. But you can assign an array to the variable `coordinates` with a certain length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
abstract class Vector implements sample {       
    private int[] coordinates;  
     public Vector (int[] coordinates){
         this.coordinates=coordinates;
     }
}
```

If you want to initialize coordinates by calling new Vector3D(1,2,3):

```
class Vector3D extends Vector {

    public Vector3D(int n1,int n2,int n3) {
       super(new int[]{n1,n2,n3});
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but can I somehow change the code so in main i could create new vector somehow like this Vector3D vec = new Vector3D(1,2,3); ?

Comment: Thanks! And the last question: is there a way to pass not declared number of variables? For example public VectorND(int...n) 
 {  
   super(new int[] {});
 } what should i write in {} in array declaration?

Answer (score 0):

Your parent class (Vector) needs to set the private field. Currently, the parameter and the instance variable are unrelated.

This would do the job:

```
public abstract class Vector implements Sample {
   private int[] coordinates;

   public Vector(int[] coordinates) {
      this.coordinates = coordinates;
   }
}



public class Vector3D {
   public Vector3D(int[] coordinates) {
      super(coordinates);
   }
}

// usage:
new Vector3D(new int[]{ 1, 2, 3 }); // Vectors coordinate size: 3. Content: 1, 2, 3
```

This would pass the Vector3Ds array to the parent and its size would be the same, as the one provided to the Vector3D class.